# How to Store date from Html form to database using java?

Tags: java, html, mysql

I have inputted the date through html page and trying to Store it to database but i got this exception java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "09/12/2016" and i am also getting an error in netbeans "to surround `Date date = (Date)formatter.parse(pswd);` with `try` and `catch`" here is my code:

```
public class OfferRide extends HttpServlet {

    protected void service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

                String status = "";              
                try {

                String userName = req.getParameter("Source");
                String email = req.getParameter("Destination");
                String pswd = req.getParameter("Date");
                SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-DD");

                java.sql.Date date = (java.sql.Date)formatter.parse(pswd);


                String id = req.getParameter("Seats");
                int seat =Integer.parseInt(id);
                String id1= req.getParameter("Phone");
                long phone = Long.parseLong(id1);
                    Connection con = DataBaseServices.getConnection();

                    PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("insert into offerride values(?,?,?,?,?)");

                    ps.setString(1, userName);
                    ps.setDate(2, date);
                    ps.setString(3, email);
                    ps.setInt(4, seat);
                    ps.setLong(5, phone);


                    int x = ps.executeUpdate();

                    if (x == 1) {

                        req.getRequestDispatcher("OfferRide1.html").include(req, resp);
                    }


                } catch (Exception e) {
                    status = e.toString();
                    //req.getRequestDispatcher("OfferRide1.html").include(req, resp);
                }

                PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();

                out.print(status);                            

    }

}
```

Comment: paste full stack trace.. how did you changed your code so it started to give compile time error when you surrounded date statement around try catch?

Comment: Can you please add the value of the `date` after parse ?

Comment: the code is deployed successfully and displayed my page too but on clicking submit button after filling info this exception "exception

java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "7898897899" " is displayed on browser @SMA

Comment: 7898897899 is out of range of integer and hence you are getting number format exception.

Comment: yeah thanks @SMA i changed the datatype type so this exception is resolved  but having this "java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "09/13/2016" " after executing the above recently edited code

Comment: Date formatter should use pattern as `MM/DD/YYYY` instead of `YYYY-MM-DD`

Comment: yeah thanks it worked ! @SMA

Answer (score 0):

place this code in between try and catch block

```
try
{
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-DD"); 
Date date = (Date)formatter.parse(pswd);
}
catch(ParseException e)
{
}
```

Comment: i did it but its still giving exception and this time its exception

java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "7878988999"

Comment: your formatting DateFormat in "YYYY-MM-DD" format. So you have to enter the String in that format. Otherwise it will through the exception. Input like "1990-01-01"

Comment: I am inputting Date through HTML(input type="Date")  page using calendar like 09/11/2016 and the trying to convert it to yyyy-MM-dd in java because in database Date type has this (yyyy-MM-dd) format. @ArvindKatte